# Adding text to an existing text element in JavaScript via DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to figure how to add text to a `p` tag or `h1` tag that already has a text node.

For example:

```js
var t = document.getElementById("p").textContent;
var y = document.createTextNode("This just got added");

t.appendChild(y);
```

```html
<p id="p">This is some text</p>
```

This code gives an error `appendChild` is not a function. Most of the help pages first create a `p` tag and then append the text.

What is the right way to add text to an existing text element?

PS: I've used `innerHTML` before to do this, but for learning purposes I want to avoid it here.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The reason that `appendChild` is not a function is because you're executing it on the `textContent` of your `p` element.

You instead just need to select the paragraph itself, and then append your new text node to that:

```js
var paragraph = document.getElementById("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("This just got added");

paragraph.appendChild(text);
```

```html
<p id="p">This is some text</p>
```

However instead, if you like, you can just modify the text itself (rather than adding a new node):

```js
var paragraph = document.getElementById("p");

paragraph.textContent += "This just got added";
```

```html
<p id="p">This is some text</p>
```

Comment: From what i can see none of these allow HTML tags to be inserted or they are parsed as strings. So i'm guessing the best way would be to create br tags or so and append it?

Comment: What do you want a line break for, @BennyThadikaran? If they're to separate two pieces of text, consider using two `p` tags. Line breaks should be sparingly used, and not used to format text.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add the content before it ??

Comment: @tkamath99 `paragraph.textContent = "This just got added before " + paragraph.textContent;`

Answer (score 29):

Instead of appending element you can just do.

```
 document.getElementById("p").textContent += " this has just been added";
```

```js
document.getElementById("p").textContent += " this has just been added";
```

```html
<p id ="p">This is some text</p>
```

Answer (score 8):

The method `.appendChild()` is used to add a **new element** NOT add text to an existing element.

**Example:**

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Reference: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

The standard approach  for this is using `.innerHTML()`. But if you want a alternate solution you could try using `element.textContent`.

**Example:**

```
document.getElementById("foo").textContent = "This is som text";
```

Reference: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

How ever this is only supported in IE 9+

Comment: A node created with `createTextNode` is a new element, so `appendChild` is valid to use

Answer (score 5):

What about this.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("p")
p.innerText = p.innerText+" And this is addon."
```

```html
<p id ="p">This is some text</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

remove `.textContent` from `var t = document.getElementById("p").textContent;`

```js
var t = document.getElementById("p");
var y = document.createTextNode("This just got added");

t.appendChild(y);
```

```html
<p id ="p">This is some text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
   });

  });
 </script>
  </head>
 <body>

 <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>



 <button id="btn1">Append text</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -5):

```js
var t = document.getElementById("p").textContent;
var y = document.createTextNode("This just got added");

t.appendChild(y);
```

```html
<p id="p">This is some text</p>
```

Comment: Please do check if your solution is working before submitting it as an answer